# show that linear functional is unbounded

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, solution-verification

Let $F:C^{1}[0,1]\to \mathbb{C}$ be equipped with the supremum norm $||.||_{\infty}$,
$F(f)=f^{\prime}(1)$.

I am trying to show that $F$ is unbounded.

Here is my idea.

I take a sequence $f_{n}=x^{n}\in C^{1}[0,1]$

then $||f_{n}||_{\infty}=\displaystyle\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|x^{n}|=1$

Also $F(f_{n})=n$

and $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{||F(f_{n})||}{||f_{n}||_{\infty}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{1}=\infty$

Is this ok?

Is $F$ continuous?

Comment: Yes, that is okay. No, $F$ is not continuous (for linear operators on normed spaces, continuous = bounded).

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I know a theorem: continuous on X $\Leftrightarrow$ bounded $\Leftrightarrow$ continuous at 0. So not bounded $\Leftrightarrow$ not continuous?(for linear functionals on normed spaces)

Comment: Yes, by contrapositive. Note that the equivalence holds for linear operators between normed spaces, but not for general topological vector spaces (you may not yet meet topological vector spaces other than normed spaces for a while, just saying that there is a difference in principle).

Comment: @HeidiE Precisely. In general, if $A \Rightarrow B$, then the contrapositive $\lnot B \Rightarrow \lnot A$ is always true (the converse $B \Rightarrow A$ and inverse $\lnot A \Rightarrow \lnot B$ are not generally true). But in the case you are given $B \Rightarrow A$ as well, (e.g. in the case you know $A \Leftrightarrow B$), then the contrapositives of *both* statements hold, i.e. $\lnot A \Leftrightarrow \lnot B$.

Comment: @Daniel@BaronVT. Thank you both for the explanations.